# How to get width of a string in plain c#

Tags: c#, wpf, string, formatted-text

I have an application where we replace place holding text with other text at run time.
While doing so I have to add character ellipses if the string goes beyond some predefined width.

So I do not have a DrawingContext available nor i have a Graphics.Measure available.

I used FormattedText but I was unable to extract the ellipted text.
I could never find the right way to use a formatted text like this.
Please help.

Comment: Do you have a specific number of characters you can use before needing to add the ellipse?

Comment: Please add the relevant tag for WPF or WinForms.

Comment: @Tejs : i do not have any specific number of characters. i have to decide it based on width.

Comment: @KendallFrey as i wanted the answer in plain c#, i didnot mentioned it. well my application is WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For WinForms, you can use the [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx) function,

and thanks to the comment from [vcjones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492405/vcsjones), using the method described at http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/glyphrun-and-so-forth/ for WPF.

Comment: is there any direct way to add ellipses to my string?

Comment: @neo: Can't you add them at the end? Otherwise, what's your requirements for adding the ellipses? Should you not break words for instance?